# Visual Studio Debug with IE

Tags: visual-studio, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Is there a way to set the debug browser to IE? I have my computer's default browser set to chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

right click on any .aspx file and right menu apears choose "Browse With..."
and there u have your list of browsers installed just choose "Set as Default" and your set to go.

Comment: what is im using asp.net mvc 3?